# Filtering dropdown list from itemsource in comboboxEdit on key down

Tags: c#, wpf

I have ComboBoxEdit which holds multiple selected items Binding to total employees collection (Active + InActive employees). But I need to show only active employees in dropdownlist.

I tried filtering (updating) on popupOpening event it showing active employees in dropdown, but the problem is if InActive is already selecteditems, it is clearing from the combobox because changing of item source.

```
private void CbCraneOps_PopupOpening(object sender, OpenPopupEventArgs e) 
{ 
  var combo = sender as ComboBoxEdit; 
  var item = combo.ItemsSource as IEnumerable<Client.LaborMgmtSystem.RosterEntry>; 
  var items = item.Where(r => r.IsActive == true);     
  this.cbCraneOps.ItemsSource = items; 
}
```

please need some clue on this. 
thanks in advance.

Comment: please post the code you've tried

Comment: private void CbCraneOps_PopupOpening(object sender, OpenPopupEventArgs e)
        {
            var combo = sender as ComboBoxEdit;
            var item = combo.ItemsSource as IEnumerable<Client.LaborMgmtSystem.RosterEntry> ;
            var items = item.Where(r => r.IsActive == true);
            this.cbCraneOps.ItemsSource = items;
        }

Comment: on popunOpening I tried to filter the Itemsource , but i need to filter dropdown as we do text input filtering usually (I think).

Comment: Please post your view model with the binding source and clarify what `ComboBoxEdit` is. If it's an extension of `ComboBox`, post the code. If it's 3rd party, please post a link to the reference. Sounds like your combo box supports multiselect (in contrast to the default WPF) because you are talking of "selected items"?

Answer (score 0):

`ComboBoxEdit` i Suppose You are using devexpress Controls.
If Yes then there is a `FilterCriteria` Option is there.
something like this will work [more here](https://www..com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T384908/how-to-hide-items-in-comboboxedit-with-checkedcomboboxstylesettings)

`combo.FilterCriteria = CriteriaOperator.Parse("IsActive=true");`

Comment: Thanks for answer , but its also giving same result as i mentioned.